# How to set the title of wizard window in Eclipse RCP 3.x?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

How to set the title of wizard window in Eclipse RCP 3.x?

This code

```
    Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();
    WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, new ChatNewWizard());
    dialog.setTitle("New chat");
    dialog.open();
```

executed from handler, has no effect.

This code

```
getShell().setText("New chat");
```

and this code

```
((WizardDialog)getContainer()).setTitle("New chat");
```

both executed from `addPages()` also have no effect.

**UPDATE**

The following code

```
public class RunWizardHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public static class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage {

        protected MyWizardPage() {
            super("Page Name", "Page Title", null);
            setDescription("Page Description");
        }

        @Override
        public void createControl(Composite parent) {

            Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());

            Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
            label.setText("Label Text");

            setControl(composite);
        }

    }

    public static class MyWizard extends Wizard {

        @Override
        public void addPages() {
            addPage(new MyWizardPage());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean performFinish() {
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        Shell shell = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getShell();
        WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, new MyWizard());
        dialog.open(); 

        return event;
    }



}
```

ran from simple sample, gives the following window

[image]

I.e. it places "Page Title" into location `1`, while I want to set text in location `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `WizardPage(String pageName, String title, ImageDescriptor titleImage)` constructor to specify a title for each page. Or call `WizardPage.setTitle(xxx)` whenever you want to change the title.

The current wizard page title overrides the normal dialog title (even if it is not set).

Update:
For the title in the dialog tile bar use the `WizardDialog.setWindowTitle` call (usually in the constructor).

Comment: I see no any dialog title in no any conditions. And this is what I want to set. See my update pls.

Comment: Small correction, it is now WizardDialog.setWindowTitle, instead it is Wizard.setWindowTitle

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way but at least it worked for me:

```
    WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wizard) {
        @Override
        public void create() {
            super.create();
            getShell().setText("Some nice window name");
        }
    };
```